# Using a different distribution profile - will my app still work?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store

I'm using a new distribution profile to put the newest version of my app onto the app store, and was wondering if that would affect anything, ie if it would still work with previous versions of the app on the app store?

Answer (score 1):

Changing up the distribution profile will not affect any existing users, and your application will function completely as expected.

Source: I've used multiple distribution profiles to update the same app.

Comment: Thanks for settling my worries. Better safe than sorry. :) (And you know how fun messing with profiles can be)

Comment: What about changing the distribution certificate? It warns that "Revoking your iPhone Distribution Certificate will cause all apps signed with this certificate to no longer operate."

Comment: It just means that you won't be able to sign anything further with that certificate.  If you keep it on your Mac, it will be invalid.